# core.js functions?

Tags: sharepoint, moss, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-designer

what is the use of MtgNavigate & MtgDelete functions defined in the core.js? when it will be used/called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Read what the actual function does.
2. You may search 12 hive (mine is at C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\12)\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS or 12\TEMPLATE\CONTROLTEMPLATES for such string to see who calls it.
3. Also use [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) to search for such string to see which methods in sharepoint dll use this javascript function (if any defined in code-behind).

I may guess that it has to do something with meeting workspaces :)